# json encoded data response is empty

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying to pull the data from the sample code below (it is through cpanel). I wanted to pull it in JSON encoded format, but there is no data that is displaying. See this screenshot, and my code below it:

[image]

Can someone help me with the problem?

```
<?php
include "db.php";

$data=array();

$q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.*,a.date_added AS date_added2,a.status AS entry_status,a.added_by AS entry_provider FROM entries a WHERE a.status = 'Approved' ORDER BY a.id DESC") 
or die(mysql_error());

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
    $data[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You use mysql**i** to get the results, but mysql without **i** to print error message. These are different extensions, so if there's an error in your `mysqli_query` call, then `mysql_error` returns empty string and execution stops. Which is what you see in the browser.

Comment: using mysql functions will not display errors. They are warning messages that says they are depcreated, instead use mysqli. That doesn't affect the query execution.

Comment: It's not about query execution. Just consider something is wrong with the query. A table or a column doesn't exist, for example, since at least its syntax is correct. If the query fails, the return value of `mysqli_query` is false, and the execution goes to the `die` part, which takes the result of `mysql_error`, which is an empty string because no other `mysql` extension function was called and no `mysql` extension error occurred. So it is `die('')`. I suppose the deprecation notice is suppressed by turning either `error_reporting` or `display_errors` off.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that your `$result` is empty.

AND

The `mysqli_fetch_object` returns you an object not array.

You can use this code to sort out your problem

```
$q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.*,a.date_added AS date_added2,a.status AS entry_status,a.added_by AS entry_provider FROM entries a WHERE a.status = 'Approved' ORDER BY a.id DESC") 
or die(mysqli_error($con));

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    array_push($data,$row);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

This can definitely help you.

Comment: i am still getting an empty result Sir,

Comment: have you tried printing out the printing out the `$row`

Comment: maybe cpanel was the problem, i guess? the permission.

Comment: cPanel has nothing to do with that. cPanel is just to access your hosting settings.

Comment: i tried printing out the $row, but no response display.

Comment: Copy the query and paste it into `phpmyadmin->your-database->sql tab`

Comment: Ive tried it in local and it is working but when it was hosted in cpanel then there is no response.